# Angular component - Create at runtime or statically with data parameter

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I implemented a custom full screen dialog component using the Angular CDK and following [this excellent blog post](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/11/20/custom-overlays-with-angulars-cdk.html).

What I am trying to do is have my component accept injected data, but also create it statically.  For example, I have a component to show some data about a customer.  I want this same component to be shown in an overlaid dialog sometime.  When the component is static, I can pass the customer data to the component via the @Input decorator.  When I create it dynamically I can use the @Inject decorator as shown in the above mentioned blog.

The component constructor looks like this:

```
export class FilePreviewOverlayComponent {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: FilePreviewOverlayRef,
    @Inject(FILE_PREVIEW_DIALOG_DATA) public image: any
   ) { }
}
```

It works fine for injecting the data when the component is dynamically created, however I get a `StaticInjectorError` when I create the component statically.  The key message in the error is `No provider for FilePreviewOverlayRef!`.

I am lost as to how I can design the component to be statically or dynamically created with the ability to inject data into the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by using `@Optional()` before `@Inject` like below.

```
export class FilePreviewOverlayComponent {
    constructor(
          @Optional() public dialogRef: FilePreviewOverlayRef,
          @Optional() @Inject(FILE_PREVIEW_DIALOG_DATA) public image: any
    ) { }
}
```

Comment: It seems so simple now reading the docs.  I don't know how my searches missed the @Optional in the documentation.   I edited your answer to include an additional needed second @Optional().   Thanks.